# Ansible - How to handle creation of data structure?

Tags: ansible

I'm not sure how I should treat my data in Ansible.
My vars file looks something like:

```
envs: [ env1, env2, env3, env4 ]
roles: [ dev, sysops, admin ]
components: [ comp1, comp2 , comp3 ]
```

I need to create, however, my issue it to create this dynamically and using a logical and efficient data structure.
Not every component in an environment has all the roles, following the example below:
comp1 will have all roles availables in the `roles` variables, for `env1`, however, this it not the case for component: `comp3` in environment: `env2` as it will only have `sysops` and `admin`.

```
comp1_env1_dev
comp1_env1_sysops
comp1_env1_admin
comp2_env1_dev
comp2_env1_sysops
comp2_env1_admin
comp3_env2_sysops
comp3_env2_admin
```

Since not every component in an environment has all the roles, I've been thinking of creating some sort of dictionary with boolean saying which of the component in an environment should have which role:

```
dict:
  comp1:
    env: [ env1, env2, env3 ]
    roles: [ dev, sysops, admin ]
 
  comp3:
    env: [ env2 ]
    roles: [ sysops, admin ]
```

The goal is to dynamically produce a list of dictionary (objects):

```
my_dict:
  - name: comp1_env1_dev
    data: XYZ
  - name: comp1_env1_sysops
    data: XYZ
...
```

**Question**: Looking at this through the eyes of Ansible. Should this be done dynamically, or should they be added manually/statically even tho it's about 300+ lines in my vars file?

Answer (score 1):

Describe the structure. For example, by the indexes of the items

```yaml
    data:
     - 0,1;0;0,1,2
     - 2;1;1,2
```

Create the lists

```yaml
  data_lists: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in data %}
    - {{ i|split(';')|map('split', ',')|map('map', 'int') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  data_lists:
    - - [0, 1]
      - [0]
      - [0, 1, 2]
    - - [2]
      - [1]
      - [1, 2]
```

Get the lists of elements

```yaml
  data_elements: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in data_lists %}
    - [{{ i.0|map('extract', components) }},{{ i.1|map('extract', envs) }},{{ i.2|map('extract', rls) }}]
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  data_elements:
    - - [comp1, comp2]
      - [env1]
      - [dev, sysops, admin]
    - - [comp3]
      - [env2]
      - [sysops, admin]
```

Create the labels

```yaml
  data_labels: |
    {% filter flatten %}
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in data_elements %}
    - {{ i.0|product(i.1)|map('join', '_')|product(i.2)|map('join', '_') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  data_labels:
  - comp1_env1_dev
  - comp1_env1_sysops
  - comp1_env1_admin
  - comp2_env1_dev
  - comp2_env1_sysops
  - comp2_env1_admin
  - comp3_env2_sysops
  - comp3_env2_admin
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    envs: [env1, env2, env3, env4]
    rls: [dev, sysops, admin]
    components: [comp1, comp2, comp3]

#   data:
#     - 0;0;0,1,2
#     - 1;0;0,1,2
#     - 2;1;1,2
    data:
      - 0,1;0;0,1,2
      - 2;1;1,2
    data_lists: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in data %}
      - {{ i|split(';')|map('split', ',')|map('map', 'int') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
    data_elements: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in data_lists %}
      - [{{ i.0|map('extract', components) }},{{ i.1|map('extract', envs) }},{{ i.2|map('extract', rls) }}]
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
    data_labels: |
      {% filter flatten %}
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in data_elements %}
      - {{ i.0|product(i.1)|map('join', '_')|product(i.2)|map('join', '_') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data_lists|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: data_elements|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: data_labels
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vladimir. As seen in my question, does it makes more sense to structure my data as in `dict:` variable? Is that a cleaner way of doing it? And the end goal is to achieve `my_dict:`

Comment: You're welcome. Without more details, it would be difficult to recommend anything. Is there any pattern? How are you going to audit such 300+ lines of random structure?